# how changing master key or other keys can provide security ?how used session key to keep the further communication between DESFire and reader?

Tags: security, session, authentication, nfc, smartcard

I am working on the ticket electronik that tickets are *DESFire* cards.

I want communications be safe . i now trying change PICC key . Before changing *DESFire master key* Authenticate with *master key* is necessary.

In [desfire sheet](http://neteril.org/files/M075031_desfire.pdf) about Authenticate at page *31* was described:

*"This procedure not only confirms that both entities
can trust each other but also generates a session key which can be used to keep the further communication
path secure. As the name “session key” implicitly indicates, each time a new authentication procedure is
successfully completed a new key for further cryptographic operations is obtained."*

i want know how changing master key or other keys can provide security ?I means is need changing keys or not? And how used session key to keep the further communication between DESFire and reader?

Comment: Why do you downvote me? I am begginer and search a lot but I only confused more!!

Comment: I know my question is so wide. But i want some link or descryptions that to be obvious , clear , useful and helpful...

Comment: It's really obvious that you must change the default Keys! You need to change keys because anybody whom knows the default keys can decrypt the data that is transfers between the card and the reader! He/She can also write on/read the card's contents. Oh, God! it is really obvious, why do you think that you can distribute the card with its defalut keys?! That means that you share the card's keys with any body else!!! We talked already about the session keys also (In the Mutual Authentication procedure.) Please do a Google for **Mutual Authentication** and "Session Keys".

Comment: You can also refer to _Global Platform_ Card specification

Comment: The hacker will try all the key numbers and key indexes with default keys. Why you don't want to change the keys? :/

Comment: If hackers try all key numbers then changing keys is meaningless . is not?

Comment: I think i can distribute card with default keys becuase we use the number of keys for example key number 0x00 contains master key if selected application be 0x00 And we just say 0x0A 0x00 that means authenticate with key number 0x00 or for reading or writing with just say read with key#6 or write with key#3 .

Comment: I means for example if master key be "af452cd4" then we try authenticate with 0x0A 0x00 not the content of key itself. So hackers use key number that involves "af452cd4" . They dont need key itself.

Comment: _If hackers try all key numbers then changing keys is meaningless . is not?_ No, It is not meaningless. A 2 key 3DES key, has 2^112 different values, and this is a lot of more than number of keys. (I think maximum is 255 for number of keys.)

Comment: we must use session keys created by mutual authentication for encryption data sanded to the card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, whether the points below answer your question, which I consider as not very clear and further blurred by your added comments.

- The default key is known to all users of an evaluation kit - therefore you surely want to change it to a value only known to you.
- Any cryptographic algorithm deserving that name is unfeasible to crack by brute force.
- Any attack will surely try the documented default value as well as frequently used patterns like "00 00...", "FF FF..", "01 02 03..". If the attack succeeds here, you have lost and the transportation provider will have severe problems since it is easy to create new tickets.
- A session key provides security against replay attacks (in any session it will have another value, not cirumventable by the outside world) and limits the amount of usable communication data with the same key for more intelligent cryptographic attacks.

Comment: do you have any simple example how using session key which is created after each authenticate command?

Comment: do you have any simple example how using session key which is created after each authenticate command?